# using regexpression to replace a word

Tags: c#, regex

I have a sentence that may have "not, or" inside.

Currently, I'm trying to test and remove these words, however, I couldn't figure out how to write a correct regex test pattern, can someone help please?

I tried with

```
string test= ""; 
string str=" some words here ";

if (str.ToLower().Contains(" not ")) {
    test = str.ToLower().Replace(" not ", " "); 
} else if (str.ToLower().Contains(" or ")) { 
    test = str.ToLower().Replace(" or ", " ");
}
```

Comment: i tried string.replace(old word, new word), it didnt work well

Comment: Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: string test= "";
string str=" some words here ";
                if (str.ToLower().Contains(" not "))
                {
                    test = str.ToLower().Replace(" not ", " ");
                }
                else if (str.ToLower().Contains(" or "))
                {
                    test = str.ToLower().Replace(" or ", " ");
                }

Comment: Perhaps some examples of the input and what you expect to get out? From what you've said I would expect string.replace to be the best solution.

Comment: somehow, string.replace did not work well

Comment: What didn't work? You should paste your sample input along with your code and then explain why the output doesn't meet your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean to replace "not" and "or"

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(?:not|or)", "", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: yes, i do mean both words "not" and "or", both are single word, not part of any other word

Comment: yours partially works, but for the word scores, it removes or from it as i tested

Comment: You need to add boundaries, then.  Try changing it from     (?:not|or) to    \b(?:not|or)\b instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) for that

```
string sString = "Sometimes not, or sometimes no";
string sNew = sString.Replace("not, or", String.Empty);
```